# Generating index for element in list of 10000 numbers

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have list of 10000 random numbers. I want the elements and their corresponding index for that element in the list between 5 and 500. I got to get the element by simple code

```
elements = [x for x in list_10000 if 5 <= x <= 500]
```

And for getting index I did

```
element_index = [list_10000.index(x) for x in list_10000 if 5 <= x <= 500]
```

The above index code took a lot of time but didn't execute. I have tried with arange and enumerate. But they gave different numbers of values than what I got with `len(elements)`
How can I get index value ??  Any help would be great !! Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to use `index(1)` two times, it will give you the same result both times, so having duplicate values will produce the same index.

You could instead use a dictionary, and immediately write both the value and it's index:

```
{i: list_10000[i] for i in range(len(list_10000)) if 5 <= list_10000[i] <= 500}
```

This will create a dictionary, where the index is the key, and the value is your number at the index.

Comment: If this has resolved your issue, please mark the answer as correct. As a side note, the other answer by @Timus will produce an array of the indices you are looking for

Comment: It will give the indices of the elements generated.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
element_index = [i for i, x in enumerate(list_10000) if 5 <= x <= 500]
```

Comment: This will enumerate the value between 5 and 500. So the size will be different.

Comment: @unicorn I don't quite understand, maybe I'm missing something: This gives you the corresponding indices to items from `elements` in `list_10000`. Is that not what you want?

Comment: No, I want the indices of the elements it picks while in the loop.

Comment: @unicorn Sorry, I'm still confused: _elements it picks while in the loop_ means `5 <= x <= 500`? And _indices of_ refers to the corresponding indices in `list_10000`?

Comment: Yes, while iterating.

Comment: @unicorn Then I don't see the difference :) If you have the nerve, you could add a little sample to your question - just for clarification.